# Host my own email in a VPS and stop using gmail, which options do I have?

Tags: vps, email, gmail, google, privacy

I'm planning to stop using some google services (like gmail for personal email, still be using for services like google code though). I'm not too paranoid, I know every service in the net is a threat to privacy. The problem with google is that it has access to all my search history, chat, e-mail, and simply associates everything - my whole life online. Is different from having some info in a flickr account, some in twitter, you can delete an account and they will not (hopefully) be merged to get more information about yourself.

I don't know if in 20 years, 40 years, this is going to be used against me, or Google becomes a corporation with different owners that are completely evil.

Anyway. I was planning to pay $20 a month to a VPS and install some kind of email server/client. I would buy a domain for me and create an email using @domain.

I would like to know some suggestions for open source solutions, I dont want something really complex ("a complete enterprise groupware solution", just the **name** "enterprise" gives me itches), I want a simple web based e-mail account. If a web interface is not possible, at least a *nix solution very light which supports pop3/imap.

Is there a "spam" group where I can get a blacklist of ips or something for spams as well, that integrates into an email solution like above? One of the things I really liked about gmail was it's spam control.

If possible, I would like to know some experiences from those who are trying to do the same as me. I'm a beginner in Linux and sys-administration, but I dont mind having to learn all that stuff. It's an opportunity to learn some new skills.

Comment: The only way to not have data collected about you, is to not use the PC, and don't go outside.

Comment: You missed the whole point of my question. I don't want to avoid having data about me collected, I just don't want to have all my **online life** collected by the **same company**. Sensitive information are going to be used in a machine I have at least some control. I will still be using my gmail account, mainly for simple google services (like google code).

Comment: If you don't want it all under Google's umbrella, you could just use one of the other email providers out there. I moved to gmail so that I didn't have to deal with running my own mail server any more, something I did for about 3 years. It was fun at the time but it gets to be too much effort.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I would like to know some suggestions for open source solutions, I dont want something really complex ("a complete enterprise groupware solution", just the name "enterprise" gives me itches), I want a simple web based e-mail account. If a web interface is not possible, at least a *nix solution very light which supports pop3/imap.

I use:

- Postfix for SMTP
- Dovecot for IMAP4 (and POP3 if you really really want it)

  - also as the SASL provider for postfix
- RoundCube for webmail when I'm away from a computer with SSH

  - SquirrelMail if you want something a lot ligher
  - or Horde IMP for something heavier
- `bogofilter` to filter spam *(although I haven't received any yet; but that's only because the mail address is not public)*

  - `spamassassin` is probably a lot better

Comment: Dropbear + USB stick could help you a lot with SSH :-) you can even carry it on your mobile... but well, if your phone is owned by Google it makes not that much sense. The better into a stick...

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't sound like you want to commit alot of time to this, so why not just use a 3rd-party email hosting service provider?  There's tons of other free ones, but I've always had good experiences with [RackSpace](http://www.rackspace.com/email_hosting/).  You can host your own domain/mailbox for $2-10 a month: spam filtering built-in, calendar, Outlook/Exchange, etc.

While your data is obviously still stored in their infrastructure, they're not in the advertising business and quote, "do not read your email". Check out their [privacy terms](http://www.rackspace.com/information/legal/mailterms.php); they're solid.

Comment: This is indeed and interesting solution. But I was interested in configuring my own infra-structure to learn more about all that stuff. If I give up, your suggestion is a good option.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, having your own hosted solution will add a layer to your privacity, but still everything will be "optionally visible" to the vps provider.

The best chance is to set up SSL certs for email with key (not stored pharaphrase, just written at launch).

Case you want all in one solution, i would recommend you VestaCP. Comes with ALL you'll need, even free SSL from letsncrypt. That makes you more easy the task of install the Roundcube panel (comes preinstalled), the DNS stuff for mailing (PTR, SPF, DKIM) etc.

Also, if you worry about your email data that much, you can set up services at the VPS but redirect ports to you own HOME SERVER, wich will host and make network stuff using your VPS's identity/IP/DNS entries and so on. I think that last is the most accurate method.

I also wanna say to don't trust bussiness terms... may be just lying.

Feel free to search me (easy by nickname) if you need some help.

I think you have a great goal, and indeed i also thoght to do that, but removing my current gmail account will be much time expensive. Anyway, i'll do some day using the last approach.